# i'm not getting the "U" shaped plot for error vs number of K in knn

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning

I'm trying to show how classification error varies with the increasing value of k in KNN. Theoretically, the error is high for lower(due to underfitting) and higher(due to overfitting) values for k and thus we get minimum error for some intermediate k thus graph comes up as somewhat upward "U" shaped. But the plot I'm getting is continuously increasing, the error is minimum for the lowest value of k(i.e. 1). Please provide an explanation for such behaviour or is it something wrong I'm doing.
here is code snippet and the image of the plot:

```
# creating odd list of K for KNN
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score
myList = list(range(1,50))

# subsetting just the odd ones
neighbors = filter(lambda x: x % 2 != 0, myList)

# empty list that will hold cv scores
cv_scores = []

# perform 10-fold cross validation
for k in neighbors:
    print(k)
    knn = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=k)
    scores = cross_val_score(knn, x_train, y_train, cv=10, scoring='accuracy')
    print(scores)
    cv_scores.append(scores.mean())


# changing to misclassification error
MSE = np.array([1 - x for x in cv_scores])

neighbors = list(filter(lambda x: x % 2 != 0, myList))
neighbors = np.array(neighbors)
# plot misclassification error vs k
plt.plot(neighbors, MSE)
plt.xlabel('Number of Neighbors K')
plt.ylabel('Misclassification Error')
plt.show()
```

[image: This is the following plot I got]